# Understanding GNU Smalltalk Closure

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

The following piece of code is giving the error   `error: did not understand '#generality'`

```
pqueue := SortedCollection new.
freqtable keysAndValuesDo: [:key :value |
   (value notNil and: [value > 0]) ifTrue: [
      |newvalue|
       newvalue := Leaf new: key count: value.
       pqueue add: newvalue.
   ]
].

    [pqueue size > 1] whileTrue:[
      |first second new_internal  newcount|
      first := pqueue removeFirst.
      second := pqueue removeFirst.
      first_count := first count.
      second_count := second count.
      newcount := first_count + second_count.
      new_internal := Tree new: nl count: newcount left: first right: second.
      pqueue add: new_internal.
    ].
```

The inconsistency is in the line `pqueue add: new_internal`. When I remove this line, the program compiles. I think the problem is related to the iteration block `[pqueue size > 1] whileTrue:` and `pqueue add: new_internal.`

Note: This is the algorithm to build the decoding tree based on huffman code.

error-message expanded

```
Object: $<10> error: did not understand #generality
MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
Character(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #generality (SysExcept.st:1448)
SmallInteger(Number)>>retryDifferenceCoercing: (Number.st:357)
SmallInteger(Number)>>retryRelationalOp:coercing: (Number.st:295)
SmallInteger>><= (SmallInt.st:215)
Leaf>><= (hzip.st:30)
optimized [] in SortedCollection class>>defaultSortBlock (SortCollect.st:7)
SortedCollection>>insertionIndexFor:upTo: (SortCollect.st:702)
[] in SortedCollection>>merge (SortCollect.st:531)
SortedCollection(SequenceableCollection)>>reverseDo: (SeqCollect.st:958)
SortedCollection>>merge (SortCollect.st:528)
SortedCollection>>beConsistent (SortCollect.st:204)
SortedCollection(OrderedCollection)>>removeFirst (OrderColl.st:295)
optimized [] in UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (hzip.st:156)
BlockClosure>>whileTrue: (BlkClosure.st:328)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (hzip.st:154)
Object: $<10> error: did not understand #generality
MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
Character(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #generality (SysExcept.st:1448)
SmallInteger(Number)>>retryDifferenceCoercing: (Number.st:357)
SmallInteger(Number)>>retryRelationalOp:coercing: (Number.st:295)
SmallInteger>><= (SmallInt.st:215)
Leaf>><= (hzip.st:30)
optimized [] in SortedCollection class>>defaultSortBlock (SortCollect.st:7)
SortedCollection>>insertionIndexFor:upTo: (SortCollect.st:702)
[] in SortedCollection>>merge (SortCollect.st:531)
SortedCollection(SequenceableCollection)>>reverseDo: (SeqCollect.st:958)
SortedCollection>>merge (SortCollect.st:528)
SortedCollection>>beConsistent (SortCollect.st:204)
SortedCollection(OrderedCollection)>>do: (OrderColl.st:64)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (hzip.st:164)
```

Comment: Please specify the dialect you're using (I assume it's GNU) and more of the error message, e.g. which class does not understand the message (possibly post a stack trace if you have one).

Comment: Looks like the SortedCollection tries to compare SmallIntegers with your added object (of class Tree?) and fails. Does your pqueue contain elements of different types? If so, make sure they are comparable via <= or supply a custom sortBlock when you construct the collection.

Comment: Yes, that's working. When I do this  [pqueue add: new_internal.]. it works

Comment: Look at the error stack. Your code is trying to compare a `SmallInteger` with the `Character` whose codePoint is `10`. This is the line feed character used for generating newlines. May be this is related to your variable `nl` in the expression `Tree new: nl count:...`?

Comment: yes, the problem was nl. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One learning we can take from this question is to acquire the habit of reading the stack trace trying to make sense of it. Let's focus in the last few messages:

```
1. Object: $<10> error: did not understand #generality
2. MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
3. Character(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #generality (SysExcept.st:1448)
4. SmallInteger(Number)>>retryDifferenceCoercing: (Number.st:357)
5. SmallInteger(Number)>>retryRelationalOp:coercing: (Number.st:295)
6. SmallInteger>><= (SmallInt.st:215)
7. Leaf>><= (hzip.st:30)
8. optimized [] in SortedCollection class>>defaultSortBlock (SortCollect.st:7)
```

Each of these lines represents the activation of a method. Every line represents a message and the sequence of messages goes upwards (as it happens in any `Stack`.) The full detail of every activation can be seen in the debugger. Here, however, we only are presented with the `class >> #selector` pair. There are several interesting facts we can identify from this summarized information:

1. In line 1 we get the actual error. In this case we got a `MessageNotUnderstood` exception. The receiver of the message was the `Character` `$<10>`, i.e., the linefeed character.
2. Lines 2 and 3 confirm that the not understood message was `#generality`.
3. Lines 4, 5 and 6 show the progression of messages that ended up sending `#generality` to the wrong object (linefeed). While 4 and 5 might look obscure for the non-experienced Smalltalker, line 6 has the key information: some `SmallInteger` received the `<=` message. This message would fail because the argument wasn't the appropriate one. From the information we already got we know that the argument was the linefeed character.
4. Line 7 shows that `SmallInteger >> #<=` came from the way the same selector `#<=` is implemented in `Leaf`. It tells us that a `Leaf` delegates `#<=` to some `Integer` known to it.
5. Line 8 says why we are dealing with the comparison selector `#<=`. The reason is that we are sorting some collection.

So, we are trying to sort a collection of `Leaf` objects which rely on some integers for their comparison and somehow one of those "integers" wasn't a `Number` but the `Character` linefeed.

If we take a look at the Smalltalk code with this information in mind we see:

- The `SortedCollection` is `pqueue` and the `Leaf` objects are the items being added to it.
- The *invariant* property of a `SortedCollection` is that it always has its elements ordered by a given criterion. Consequently, every time we `add:` an element to it, the element will be inserted in the correct position. Hence the comparison message `#<=`.
- Now let's look for `#add:` in the code. Besides of the one above, there is another below:

  ```
    new_internal := Tree new: nl count: newcount left: first right: second.
    pqueue add: new_internal.
  ```

  This one is interesting because is where the error happens. Note however that we are not adding a `Leaf` here but a `Tree`. But wait, it might be that a `Tree` and a `Leaf` belong to the same hierarchy. In fact, both `Tree` and `Leaf` represent *nodes* in an acyclic graph. Moreover, the code confirms this idea when it reads:

  ```
    Leaf new: key count: value.
    ...
    Tree new: nl count: newcount left: first right: second.
  ```

See? Both `Leaf` and `Tree` have some `key` (the argument of `new:`) and some `count`. In addition, `Trees` have `left` and `right` branches, which `Leaf`s not (of course!)

So, in principle, it would be ok to add instances of `Tree` to our `pqueue` collection. This cannot be what causes the error.

Now, if we look closer to the way the `Tree` is created we can see a suspicious argument `nl`. This is interesting because of two reasons: (i) the variable `nl` is not defined in the part of the code we were given and (ii) the variable `nl` is the `key` that will be used by the `Tree` to respond to the `#<=` message. Therefore, `nl` must be the linefeed character `$<10>`. Which makes a lot of sense because `nl` is an abbreviation of `newline` and in the Linux world newlines are linefeeds.

**Conclusion:** The problem seems to be caused by the wrong argument `nl` used for the `Tree`'s key.